# Counting the number of for, while, do/while loops in a c program

Tags: c

Okay so for an assignment I have to count the number of for, while, do/while loops in a c program (I scan it as a text file) First thing that came to mind was to write a function that scans the file for keywords and it works!

```
int wc(char filename[], char word[]){
FILE *fp;
int count = 0;
int ch, len;

if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filename, "r")))

return -1;
len = strlen(word);
for(;;)
{
    int i;
    if(EOF==(ch=fgetc(fp))) break;
    if((char)ch != *word) continue;
    for(i=1;i<len;++i)
    {
        if(EOF==(ch = fgetc(fp))) goto end;
        if((char)ch != word[i])
        {
            fseek(fp, 1-i, SEEK_CUR);
            goto next;
        }
    }
   count++;
    next: ;
}
end:
fclose(fp);
return count;
}
```

But the next problem I ran into is that when it scans for a keyword a do/while loop and while loop both contain the same keyword sooo it will output incorrect info. Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: Maybe these steps would help. 1) extract all instances of `for`, `do` and `while`. 2) count them (n1, n2, n3). 3) number of for = n1; number of do = n2; number of while = n3 - n2. Does that work?

Comment: Wow I haven't though of that. Yes that would work perfectly thank you very much sir :)

Answer (score 0):

First, there are a few things wrong with your code, semantic wise.

`goto end === break`

`goto next === continue`

Secondly, what you want to do is create a parser. Google some information on that. Learn how `flex` and `bison` work.

Comment: Because the assignment is due tonight could you help me with actual code or give me some more detailed steps into creating a parser for this specific operation?

Comment: @user3225919: Your failure to budget enough time to do your assignment is not an incentive for us to do it for you. Writing a lexer and parser is a complex and difficult task. You should ask your professor or TA for a clarification of the assignment; if they are expecting you to write your own lexer and parser they should be giving you weeks or months to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these steps would help:

1. extract all instances of for, do and while.
2. count them (n1, n2, n3).
3. number of for = n1; number of do = n2; number of while = n3 - n2.

Comment: His overall approach of "count the instances" doesn't work in C. For example, it fails miserably with the file `main() { char *str = "for a while, I looked for things to do while the cat was away."; }`

Comment: @dlev - clearly. It is not obvious from the level of the question whether this is a "write a lexer" assignment, or as simple as my answer suggests. Not hard to remove all strings and comments from the code, then run the above; but have to make sure that you don't count variables with `for` in the name, etc...